# Holding time in Markov processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

I was trying to solve same past exams regarding stochastic processes and I think that the solutions may be wrong. I am posting here because I would like some clarification if actually are the solutions wrong or maybe I am not really understand some concept.

I have this generator matrix for a health-sick-dead model $$ Q =
    \begin{vmatrix}
    -0.05 & 0.04 & 0.01 \\
    0.006 & -0.026 & 0.02 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

The question asks to calculate $_{10}p_{40}^\overline{00}$

For me the solution should be $_{10}p_{40}^\overline{00}$ = $e^{-\int_{40}^{40+10}0.05t\,dt}$ since this is a time inhomogeneous markov process (right?). I mean, the age of the person interferes the transition between the three states.

But the solution states that the answer is $_{10}p_{40}^\overline{00}$ = $e^{-0.05*10}$, which accounts only for the length of the time and not the age of the person.

Comment: I don't understand your notation ${}_{10}p_{40}^{\overline{00}}$. What is this supposed to denote?